# cashier program, add two or more goods in one invoice number

Tags: c#, mysql, database, datagridview

i am very new to c#.. i tried to make a cashier program, but i stuck in, to make the program can add two or more goods in one invoice number....

this my database design, tsiswa show costumers database, tbukux show books database, tpinjam show the purchases and tdetpinjam show the purcases details

[image]

i really don't know how to do this.. please help me.. i really appreciate it

and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Please post your C# where you try to add the items.

Answer (score 0):

Have any code to show us? This will help us see what you are currently trying to do.

A [Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) would go a long way here. For example: `Key = invoice` and `Value = item`

Say you have invoice `#000001` and two items `oatmeal` and `cereal`. You want to add `oatmeal` and `cereal` in association to invoice `#000001`.

Comment: i am sorry mister, but i really don't know to do it... so i don't have any code to show you